# WCF подключение к сервису. Обработка ошибок

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Есть сервис и клиент

```
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITaskCallback))]
    public interface ITaskTicker
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Subscribe();
        [OperationContract]
        void Unsubscribe();
        [OperationContract]
        IList<Task> GetTasks();
        [OperationContract]
        Task InsertTask(Task task);
    }
```

Сервис запускаю в консольном приложении

```
 var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TaskTicker));
 host.Open();
```

Добавил сервис через reference
В клиенте подключаюсь к сервису так

```
public class CurrentTasks : BindableBase, ITaskTickerCallback
{
        private CurrentTasks()
        {            
            proxy = new TaskTickerClient(new InstanceContext(this));
            try
            {
                proxy.Subscribe();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.This(ex.Message);
            }            
        }
}
```

Если сервис запущен, то все работает отлично. 
А если сервис не запущен, то в дебагере сыпяться исключения, но программно я их не могу обработать. Т.е. блок catch не отрабатывает. Почему? Как правильно подключаться к сервису, чтобы обработать исключения?
Для клиента использую WPF и Prism

Comment: Попробуйте создание proxy перенести в try {}

Comment: Ничего не поменялось